# How can I differentiate values in my JSON Array from other values in my ListView?

Tags: android, json

I have a `JSON Array` which consists of some contacts in my phonebook who are also users of my app. For example, the JSON Array might look like :

```
[{"contact_phonenumber":"11111"},{"contact_phonenumber":"22222"},{"contact_phonenumber":"33333"}]
```

`phoneNumberofContact` is a string which, in the `do` statement in my code below, returns every contact in my phone. How can I check which `phoneNumberofContact` numbers appear in my `JSON Array` and then, besides those contacts in the `ListView` put the words '- app user'. My `ListView` is working fine, I just want to add this feature in.

So, for example, for the number `11111` I would have in my `ListView` :

```
Joe Blogs - app user
11111
```

Here's my code:

```
JSONArray jsonArrayContacts = response;
//response is something like [{"contact_phonenumber":"11111"}, etc...]

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_contact);


        //selectPhoneContacts is an empty array list that will hold our SelectPhoneContact info
        selectPhoneContacts = new ArrayList<SelectPhoneContact>();

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewPhoneContacts);

}


//******for the phone contacts in the listview

    // Load data in background
    class LoadContact extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {


//          we want to delete the old selectContacts from the listview when the Activity loads
//          because it may need to be updated and we want the user to see the updated listview,
//          like if the user adds new names and numbers to their phone contacts.
            selectPhoneContacts.clear();

//          we have this here to avoid cursor errors
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();

            }


            try {

//                get a handle on the Content Resolver, so we can query the provider,
                cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver()
//                the table to query
                 .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                null,
                                null,
                                null,
//               display in ascending order
                 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");

//                get the column number of the Contact_ID column, make it an integer.
//                I think having it stored as a number makes for faster operations later on.
//                get the column number of the DISPLAY_NAME column
                int nameIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
//                 get the column number of the NUMBER column
                int phoneNumberofContactIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

                cursor.moveToFirst();

//              We make a new Hashset to hold all our contact_ids, including duplicates, if they come up
                Set<String> ids = new HashSet<>();

                do {

                    System.out.println("=====>in while");

//                        get a handle on the display name, which is a string
                    name = cursor.getString(nameIdx);

//                        get a handle on the phone number, which is a string
                    phoneNumberofContact = cursor.getString(phoneNumberofContactIdx);


                    //----------------------------------------------------------


                    // get a handle on the phone number of contact, which is a string. Loop through all the phone numbers
//                  if our Hashset doesn't already contain the phone number string,
//                    then add it to the hashset
                    if (!ids.contains(phoneNumberofContact)) {
                        ids.add(phoneNumberofContact);

                                SelectPhoneContact selectContact = new SelectPhoneContact();

                                selectContact.setName(name);
                                selectContact.setPhone(phoneNumberofContact);
                                selectPhoneContacts.add(selectContact);
                            }

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(NewContact.this, "what the...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
                //   cursor.close();
            } finally {

            }


    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.close();

    }
    return null;
}


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            adapter = new SelectPhoneContactAdapter(selectPhoneContacts, NewContact.this);

//                    we need to notify the listview that changes may have been made on
//                    the background thread, doInBackground, like adding or deleting contacts,
//                    and these changes need to be reflected visibly in the listview. It works
//                    in conjunction with selectContacts.clear()
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first, you can parse the `jsonArrayContacts` to a List:

```
 final List<String> responseContacts = new ArrayList<String>();
                    try {
                        JSONArray responseObject = new JSONArray(response);
                        for (int i = 0; i < responseObject.length(); i++) {
                            final JSONObject obj = responseObject.getJSONObject(i);
                            responseContacts.add(obj.getString("contact_phonenumber"));
                        }
                      //  System.out.println("the matching contacts of this user are :" + responseContacts);

                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

after you get your local contacts, then you have two sets of contacts, so it's easy to check which number appears in your json array contacts.
And then you can pass the `responseContacts` into `SelectPhoneContactAdapter` during you initialize it, and in `getView()` method of the adapter, you can know whether you need to put the words '- app user' to your item view or not.

Comment: Looks good, I will implement this evening and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Great! I am looking forward your result!

Comment: Your code works - modified and edited it a small bit in the answer -  and I'd say it's the right track to achieve my objective. Will look at the adapter and getView() parts now, answer accepted.

Comment: That is really great!